# How to view tab names in tab layout with viewpager in android json?

Tags: android

How to add json using Viewpager at load page.already use fragmentTablayout offline data. how to get json array select category name error [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XAia.png)  **   shopmenu name array name how to set select name android

> @Override
> public String getPageTitle(int position) {** this offline data show

```
`@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle    savedInstanceState) {
    if (AppConfig.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_layout_rtl, container, false);
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_layout, container, false);
    }
    sharedPref = new SharedPref(getActivity());
    tab_background = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_background);
    smartTabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    if (sharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()) {
        tab_background.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToolbarDark));
        smartTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccentDark));
    } else {
        tab_background.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }
    initViewPager();
    return view;

}

public void initViewPager() {
    if (AppConfig.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
        viewPagerRTL = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_rtl);
        viewPagerRTL.setOffscreenPageLimit(tab_count);
        viewPagerRTL.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tab_count));
        smartTabLayout.post(() -> smartTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPagerRTL));

    } else {
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tab_count);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tab_count));
        smartTabLayout.post(() -> smartTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager));
    }
}

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int noOfItems;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int noOfItems) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        this.noOfItems = noOfItems;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        if (position == 0) {
            return new FragmentHome();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return new FragmentHome1();
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return new FragmentHome2();
        } else if (position == 3) {
            return new FragmentHome3();
        } else if (position == 4) {
            return new FragmentHome4();
        }else if (position == 5) {
            return new FragmentHome5();
        }else if (position == 6) {
            return new FragmentHome6();
        }else if (position == 7) {
            return new FragmentHome7();
        }else if (position == 8) {
            return new FragmentHome8();
        }else if (position == 9) {
            return new FragmentHome9();
        }else if (position == 10) {
            return new FragmentHome10();
        }else if (position == 11) {
            return new FragmentHome11();
        }else if (position == 12) {
            return new FragmentHome12();
        }

        else {
            return new FragmentHome();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return noOfItems;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
    com.Tnpsc.Group.models.shopmenu Menu1 = shopmenu.get(1);
    String categoryName = Menu1.category_name;

            return getResources().getString(Menu1.category_name);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
        } else if (position == 3) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
        } else if (position == 4) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
        }else if (position == 5) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);

        }else if (position == 6) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);

        }else if (position == 7) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
        }else if (position == 8) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
        }else if (position == 9) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
        }else if (position == 10) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
        }else if (position == 11) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);

        }else if (position == 12) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
        }else {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_home);
        }
    }
}

}
```

`
model

```
`public class shopmenu implements Serializable {

public int cid = -1;
public String category_name;
public String category_image;
public String recipes_count;

}
```

`

How to name tablayout android